Search result returns empty list(args wasn't passed to Nav correctly)
I have been working on a notice app based on the Inventory App(Tutorial App that Android Studio provides in their CodeLab). I tried to add a searchbar in Homescreen so that the users can search items with keywords in their names. I made no changes to the original ViewModels and Screens except adding the SearchBar on HomeScreen. All the original functions work well. When I input the searchQuery and tapped search on the simulator, the SearchResultScreen came with no matching result. But the data is already stored in database. I think it should be the way that I implemented the navigateToSearchResult was wrong. The searchQuery: String as argument maybe hasen't been passed to NavGraph. But really have no idea how to fix it.
InventoryNavGraph.kt
///
composable(
            route = SearchResultDestination.routeWithQuery,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(SearchResultDestination.searchQueryArg) {
                type = NavType.StringType
            })
        ) 
///

SearchResultScreen.kt
///
object SearchResultDestination : NavigationDestination {
    override val route = "search_result"
    override val titleRes = R.string.search_result
    const val searchQueryArg = "searchQuery"
    val routeWithQuery = "$route/{$searchQueryArg}"
}
///

HomeScreen.kt
///
fun HomeScreen(
    navigateToItemEntry: () -> Unit,
    navigateToItemUpdate: (Int) -> Unit,
    navigateToSearchResult: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val homeUiState by viewModel.homeUiState.collectAsState()
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    var searchQuery by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
///
topBar = {
            SearchBar(
                value = searchQuery,
                onValueChange = { searchQuery = it },
                onSearchClicked =  navigateToSearchResult,
                onClearClick = { searchQuery = ""  })
        }
///
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onClearClick: () -> Unit,
    placeholder: String = "Search",
    icon: ImageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
    onSearchClicked: (String) -> Unit

) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        placeholder = { Text(text = placeholder) },
        leadingIcon = {
             Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = "Search icon")
        },
        trailingIcon = if (value.isNotEmpty()) {
            {
                IconButton(onClick = onClearClick) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear, contentDescription = "Clear text")
                }
            }
        } else null,
        singleLine = true,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
            onSearchClicked("%$value%")
        })
    )
}

